# From program android studio

Tags: android, kotlin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4FCD.png) Hello, I have a problem installing the gradle 8.0 file, please tell me where to unzip this archive. I couldn't install it through the program itself, I got an error. Can you tell me where this file is open?

I tried to install through the program itself but it didn't work.